# 'UnityWebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'result'

Tags: c#, api, unity-game-engine, dialogflow-es, unitywebrequest

When I use the code satable for the unity 2021 in the unity 2019.

The console shows that

> 'UnityWebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'result' and no accessible extension method 'result' accepting a first argument of type 'UnityWebRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Bugs/problem:

```
if (req.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError || req.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError)
```

I expect I can use those code on unity 2019 with other codes and works.

Comment: The `result` field was added in 2020.1. If you are using 2019 you'll need to modify the code.

Answer (score 2):

Simply consult the API!

[`result`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest-result.html) was added in version 2020.3.

Prior to that version simply follow the examples from the according version API e.g. [2019.4 API](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Get.html)

You can e.g. simply check if there is any content in [`error`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest-error.html)

```
using (var webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri))
{
    yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(webRequest.error))
    {
        Debug.LogError($"Error {webRequest.responseCode} - {webRequest.error}");
        yield break;
    }

    Debug.Log(webRequest.downloadHandler.text);
}
```

or if you want to further differentiate [`isNetworkError`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest-isNetworkError.html) (includes errors like no internet connection, host not reachable, DNS resolve error etc) and [`isHttpError`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest-isHttpError.html) (basically same as `responseCode >= 400`)

---

If your question is about downwards compatibility but support both versions either stick to the pre-2020.3 way or use [Conditional Compilation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html) and do e.g.

```
#if UNITY_2020_3_OR_NEWER
    if(webRequest.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError || webRequest.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError)  
#else
    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(webRequest.error))
#endif
    {
        Debug.LogError($"Error {webRequest.responseCode} - {webRequest.error}");
        yield break;
    }
```